# Meteor's Houston:admin not working with Iron:router

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm using **[iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router)** to define paths in my Meteor application.

Now, I want to use **[houston:admin](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin)** package to have a Django-like admin interface for Meteor's Mongodb.

The issue is that:

- if I use houston's admin **without adding iron's router**, it works flawlessly by simply navigating to **localhost:3000/admin**
- if I use houston's admin **after adding iron's router**, when I (manually) navigate to **localhost:3000/admin**, it redirect me to the default route (/config) I set client-side.

Routing rules are defined in **shared/lib/routing.js**.

Default route is defined client-side in **client/app.js** as:

```
 Router.go('config');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to only enforce the default route if the current path does not begin with */admin*

in **client/app.js**

```
if(!Iron.Location.get().path.match(/^\/admin/)){
  Router.go('config');
}
```

Comment: 2nd one works. first doesn't ( can't read property .route of undefined)